# How to search a string within another string in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I want to need to find a string, replace the string by another string.

For example, replace 'apple' to 'orange' in the following string.

"I love apple"

What function should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged C++/CLI, I'm assuming you're referring to managed [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx) objects.

If so, then there's a [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method on the String class you can use.

```
String^ orig = "I love apple";
String^ modified = orig->Replace("apple", "orange");
```